# context.fileOpenInput(...) - file does not exist...but it does

Tags: java, android

I am probably doing something stupid here but my app cannot read data from the external storage. But i can write files just fine. In fact, i pull the files from an FTP server and write them to external storage which works fine. But as soon as I try to read them with:

```
getApplicationContext().openFileInput(files[i]);
```

I get java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/co.za.infestation.opendesign.app/files/event1.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Which is weird because I know the files are there. And i know files[i] has the correct file name because I printed them before after:

```
String[] files = getExternalFilesDir(null).list();
```

Yes I did add the permissions in the manifest file... And yes, i did hardcode the file names without success..Maybe i need more coffee.

Thanks!

Comment: is there a space in the filename? because android got problems handling spaces in file names..

Comment: I thought that might be the problem so i changed them all to lowercase names without any spaces. Still nothing.

Comment: is there any chance you're running android 4.4?

Comment: 4.2.2. and if i want to cater for like 3.0 to latest is there something different i must do?

Comment: Did you test on other devices (or emulator) if the problem still exists?

Comment: samething on my S4 and S4 Mini

Comment: Well, I really can't help you here :/. I would suggest testing on an emulator (or just a non-samsung device, they tend to tweak android), but I'm clueless to what the problem might be

Comment: Going to try emulator now. I just hate it because it is so slow. But yeah, thanks. I will report back if i get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
openFileInput()
```

is for opening files which reside in private internal memory. You can see the error path:

```
/data/data/co.za.infestation.............
```

Try to open with a

```
FileInputStream()
```

instead.

Comment: Aaaah this got me to think back to 11th grade java where we used FileReader(..) to read from txt files. Thanks a ton. Now to read the images!